# Finding a word in a string in python

Tags: python-3.8

i am just trying to find out a word noone in a string whether it is in lower case or upper case or mixed.

This is the code:

```
post= "hi noone bro"
a = "noone"
print(a in post)
```

If I replace `noone` with `noOne` it shows False. How can I fix it?

Comment: Just convert both to lower case before checking.

Answer (score 2):

You can apply `.lower()` or `.upper()` to strings when finding matches, effectively eliminating casing.

So this would return true: `"noone".lower() == "noOne".lower()`

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert both to either `lowercase` or `uppercase` using `.lower()` or `.upper()` or can do something like this.

```
post= "hi noone bro"
a = "noOne"
print(a.casefold() in post.casefold())
```